# Back button takes me back to page 1 when that was not the previous page

Tags: bug

I've tried on Meta.SO and SO. If I'm on questions page 2 and I go into a question, then hit the back button, I should go back to questions page 2 (or 3 or whatever). But it's taking me back to questions page 1. This did not happen on Fantasy&SciFi.SE.

Is this a bug or is it just my browser? I'm using Chrome on Windows 10 if that helps.

Edit: This problem is still happening, and I just tried it in IE. I don't like using IE, but I'm sort of desperate to be able to go through MSO and SO. I like coming here, but this is a real pain. Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Not just you. Looks like SO&Meta.SO use an ajax paging system that isn't used on the other SE sites yet.

Comment: I see. So does that mean all the other sites will break now? I wanted to do some editing on SO but I can't do it like this.

Comment: I posted originally on the 16th, but I'm glad it's not just me. Yours doesn't have an answer yet either, but maybe one of us will get an answer. I sure hope so, this is a real problem.